# If no items in cart, warning appears

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I have a  small issue with sessions. I have built a small shopping cart-esque section on a site which does nearly what I want it to do. One issue is that when I visit my *basket* and have NO items in it, it throws up an error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/andydownham/site.com/wp-content/themes/theme/basket.php on line 28
```

I guess it needs something like `'if items are in cart' > use normal code > else display 'sorry there are no items in your cart'` it's just I don't know how exactly how to implement this.

Here is the code I am using to store things into the session

```
<?php
session_start();
//var_dump($_POST);
//print_r($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['event_orders'][] = $_POST['event_id'];
?>
```

and this is the code I am using on the basket page:

```
<?php
session_start();

foreach($_SESSION['event_orders'] AS $event_id){
    echo '<div class="grad basket">';

    echo '<div class="thumb">';
    $EM_Event = em_get_event($event_id);
    echo $EM_Event->output('#_EVENTIMAGE{72,72}');
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="basket-title"><h2>';
    echo '<a href="';
    $EM_Event = em_get_event($event_id);
    echo $EM_Event->output('#_EVENTURL');
    echo '">';
    $EM_Event = em_get_event($event_id);
    echo $EM_Event->output('#_EVENTNAME');
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<div class="basket-dates"> Dates:';
    $EM_Event = em_get_event($event_id);
    echo $EM_Event->output('#_EVENTDATES');
    echo '</div></div>';
    echo '<div class="klear"></div>';
    echo '<input type="submit" class="remove" value="remove" />';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you look into separating your logic from your HTML, and output your HTML as much as possible without PHP. You'll find that separating the two will make your programs much more readable, and editing the layout becomes much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation, I agree, tho I am not sure how to do this (I am very new to PHP, and have basic knowledge) if you have a link at hand with some info on how this is done I would be grateful

Comment: [This](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engine-in-php) is a good theoretical discussion about templating engines (it is a bit advanced, but give it a go nevertheless). Search for "Zend_View", "Twig" or "Smarty" to learn more about various approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that `$_SESSION['event_orders']` exists (even if it's an empty array). You can check that with the [empty](http://php.net/empty) function (which will catch the empty array as well):

```
if (empty($_SESSION['event_orders'])) {
  // Cart is empty
} else {
  foreach(...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

You need to be careful with `empty`, though. These things are also considered "empty" (from the manual):

> ```
> *  "" (an empty string)
> * 0 (0 as an integer)
> * 0.0 (0 as a float)
> * "0" (0 as a string)
> * NULL
> * FALSE
> * array() (an empty array)
> * var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
> ```

Especially note that **the string containing "0" is considered empty**! That means that if you, in the future somewhere, have a HTML form where the user may input values and the user puts in the number `0`, that field will be considered "empty" by this function. That is not always what you want. In this case, though, it is useful for checking the "emptiness" of your array.

Comment: I tend to use `array_key_exists('event_orders', $_SESSION)` so as to avoid any issues with `empty()`.

Comment: halfer, then you'd need to implement a check for the empty array *as well*. I would use `isset($_SESSION['event_orders'])` (since it is shorter than `array_key_exists`) but it has the same drawback. I think empty is fine here because the data is not from the outside so we have control over the datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a condition to check if any basket items exist in your session varaible:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['event_orders'])){
    foreach($_SESSION['event_orders'] AS $event_id){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing empty session to foreach loop, so it throws an error, because it expects array.
So you could check whether session is array (php function: is_array($array)), whether check if array is empty (php function: empty($array)).
Other variants are not good, but it can be done.